# Accessing fields defined in a OneToOneRelation in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am new to Django and trying to access the custom fields but dont have any luck.

`Models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

`forms.py`

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':50, 'rows': 5}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'bio')
```

`views.py`

```
def register(request):
registered = False
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        registered = True
        login(request, user)
    else:
        print(user_form.errors)
else:
    user_form = UserForm
return render(request, 'accounts/register.html',
                    {'user_form':user_form, 'registered': registered})

@login_required
def current_user(request):
current = request.user
# profile = User.objects.get(username=current.username)
return render(request,'accounts/profile_detail.html',{"username":current.username,
                                                        "email":current.email,"id":current.id,
                                                        "bio":current.bio})
```

I am trying to access the bio of a user. It keeps saying the field doesn't exist. What I want to do is access bio in the html file:

> {{ bio }}

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `{{ user.userprofile.bio }}` as `user` will always be included in the template content and user will have relation to `UserProfile`

Comment: The bio field isnt showing, i have been querying it but looks like it didnt even add bio to it

Comment: Have you added `post_save()` signals to create the actual `profile` and save it? I would recommend following tutorial like this [one](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) or [this](https://blog.khophi.co/extending-django-user-model-userprofile-like-a-pro/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get a `bio` attribute out of a `User` which indeed does not have such attribute. Remember: you defined `bio` in `UserProfile` class.

Django helps you accessing fields across relations. They are called "*related fields*". In your case it should be enough to use:

```
bio = user.userprofile.bio
```

Or to use the user from the request:

```
bio = request.user.userprofile.bio
```

Then you can pass this variable to the context to `render`

Comment: It seems I didn't add a userprofile. After adding it and saving it, it work as you said.

Comment: Forgot to run migrations?

Comment: No, I was only saving the User model. I didn't even use UserProfile. Once I made a UserProfile in the register and saved it, it worked as intended

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do `{{ user.user.bio }}` since you have a `OneToOneField` with the `User` model. I'm not sure if you can access the bio directly from `{{ user.bio }}`.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer. Though I am not sure `{{ user.user }}` is defined

Comment: yes, you are right, you call the model name, which is in this case `user.userprofile`, not `user.user` as I had suggested @LaurynasTamulevičius